# How to update constraint whenrotate to landscape

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have added a constraints to an `UIImageView` in this way

```
 //-----------Add constraints to rightoval image-----------------

NSArray *constr_V2=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[rightOval(210)]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil views:back];

NSArray *constr_H2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-rgtOvalX-[rightOval(65)]|"
                                                            options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                            metrics:metrices
                                                              views:back];

[self.view addConstraints:constr_V2];
[self.view addConstraints:constr_H2];
```

This `rgtOvalX`value I calculated in this way

```
float rgtX=dm.screenWidth-65;
```

65 is my image view width. Its fine in portrait view. But in landscpe view its still takes X position same as the portrait X position. How can I update the constraint when the phone rotates to landscape mode. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you will need to change the way you create `constr_H2`, cause you need to have access to constraint, that places `rightOval` left edge.

```
NSArray *constr_H2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-rgtOvalX-[rightOval(65)]|"
                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                        metrics:metrices
                                                          views:back];
//This constant should be available in all view controller. Make property, for example
NSLayoutConstraint *rightOvalLeftEdge = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:<#rightOval#>
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:<#rightOvalSuperView#>
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                    multiplier:1.
                                                                      constant:0];
```

Second, in your viewController in method [-traitCollectionDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITraitEnvironment/traitCollectionDidChange:)

```
- (void) traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];


    if(previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass) {
        if(self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)
            self.rightOvalLeftEdge.constant = <#Calculate space in portrait orientation#>
        else if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular)
            self.rightOvalLeftEdge.constant = <#Calculate space in album orientation#>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. now I have implemented in this way. And when I rotate the phone this traitcollection event also firing but my image view doesnt change its position. do I need to do some additional thing?

Comment: for portrait I calculated as dm.screenwidth-65 and for landscape dm.screenwidth-65

Comment: Have you added rightOvalLeftEdge as a constraint? And, no offence, I don't see difference between ` dm.screenwidth-65` and ` dm.screenwidth-65` =)

Comment: Thank you somuch. I have forgotten it :)

Comment: and can you explain me that rightovelLeftEdge constraint. Because I dont understand why  used toItem:<#rightOvalSuperView#>
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft this left attribute  of the parent view of that view?

Comment: @user1960169 Because in your original implementation it was that way. When you create constraint s with Visual Format, character '|' means superview

Comment: Thanks,, but why NSLayoutAttributeLeft? Cant we put NSLayoutAttributeTrailing?

Comment: @user1960169 Oh, in that meaning. Yes, of course you can. As I understand, you rather need NSLayoutAttributeLeading, but it depends